# Pymongo doing match project query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am having my mongodb query and trying to implement it using pymongo. The query is trying to do an aggregation.This works fine in mongodb robomongo. When trying to implement the same with pymongo in python, i am getting errors

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      name: "Sam"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "name": "$name",
      "technologies": {
        $map: {
          input: "$technology",
          as: "t",
          in: "$$t.technologyName"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

I have tried executing the same with pymongo

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
connection_uri = f"mongodb://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db_name}?{args}"
client = MongoClient(connection_uri)
db = client[db_name]

testCollection = db['artifactCollection']

testCollection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "name" : "Sam"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "technologies": {
        "$map": {
          input: "$technology",
          as: "t",
          in: "$$t.technologyName"
        }
      },
      "sectors": {
        "$map": {
          input: "$sector",
          as: "s",
          in: "$$s.sectorName"
        }
      },
      "accounts": {
        "$map": {
          input: "$account",
          as: "a",
          in: "$$a.accountName"
        }
      },
      "regions": {
        "$map": {
          input: "$region",
          as: "r",
          in: "$$r.regionName"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Giving me error.. I wanted to execute the query with pymongo.. I tried the query in robomongo and is working fine.

```
as: "t",
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping `input`, `as` and `in` keys in quotation marks?

Comment: vahdet is right. The mongoshell is more forgiving of naked keys (keys without quotes) than Python is. Add quotes and you should be good to go.